# PHP Session Array - Cart - Cross browser update "lag"

Tags: php, session, shopping-cart

I am using $_SESSION Array to control products added to a shopping cart.

I see differences between browsers on how quick the SESSION "accepts" to show newest data in the SESSION.

A:
I add something quickly to the cart / update the amount in the cart.

Mozilla : Direct effect - No problems

IE      : No direct response - Wait 10 seconds refresh.. : Correct data showed

Chrome  : No direct response - Wait 10 seconds refresh.. : Correct data showed

//

B:
I add something with a 10 second waiting time between actions:

Mozilla : Direct effect - No problems

IE      : Direct effect - No problems

Chrome  : Direct effect - No problems

What is the reason that there is only direct live effect in mozilla and not in IE / Chrome ?
And how do i solve this problem ?

---

```
         function basket_skuadd(item) {
         var prod_sku_passed = ($(item).attr("id"));

         var result = $("#basket").empty();
         $.post('../coo.php',{cookieskuadd : prod_sku_passed},
         function(data){
         result.append(data);
         location.reload(true); 
         }  ) 
         }
```

.. coo.php

```
        elseif (!empty($_POST['cookieskuadd']))
        {
        session_start(); 
        //check for current product in visitor's shopping cart content
        $i=0;
        while ($i<count($_SESSION["prodsku"]) && $_SESSION["prodsku"][$i] 
        != $_POST["cookieskuadd"]) $i++;
        if ($i < count($_SESSION["prodsku"])) //increase current product's item quantity
        {
        $_SESSION["prodpcs"][$i]++;
        }
```

---

I have found that :

```
        location.reload(true);
```

is causing the problem. I though then need another solution.

I added the reload function due to the main page needs to update, when the user is inside the shopping cart.

Without reload Coo.php is updated just fine and shows up nice in a DIV in the top of the page.

Comment: "I see differences between browsers" --- there are no differences. Session is (usually) stored on the server thus it doesn't matter what the client is. You have some issues with your code, which doesn't behave expectedly

Comment: Depends how you save your data. Maybe you are using ajax and the browser doesn't execute it quickly because of other javascript slowdowns somewhere else who knows. We would need more info on your whole setup.

Comment: Either processes still running (so call `session_write_close()` as soon as possible), or otherwise it smells like a `KeepAlive` problem, or something served with a wrong `Content-Length`.

Comment: Ok.. I will try to add session_write_close() and see if this will change something.

Comment: No change when using the session_write_close() .. I added the code i use.